# How to massage redux data into props in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am trying to massage some redux data into the props of a child component. The issue is that I am not sure how to do so with this type of data. I would just like to grab the first exchange  there is from the data returned in redux.

Comment: Its really hard to understand what's going on here. What does the render function belong to? There's a lot going on in this one file. Also have you looked into making slices and selectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just take the first element of the Object.keys array & use it as a key.

```
this.props.exchangeMarketsData[Object.keys(this.props.exchangeMarketsData)[0]]
```